# Isotope filter checkbox and radio

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, filtering, jquery-isotope

Anyone know how to set isotop with radio button and checkboxes?

I have
ex:

Gender = Male/Female (Radio button)

language = arabic, english, french (Checkboxes)

Country = UAE, USA, etc... (Checkboxes)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [this](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/btFfG) for checkboxes and [this](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qlwyL) for radiobuttons

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay.. But i tried, but its not filtering.. see http://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/pvYOwR

Comment: Do F12 and see the error. It is saying createContent not defined.

Comment: Hi thanks,on the console panel no error showing :(
i change the style, please have a look.. sorry for the english, http://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/raRqGP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( function() {
  // init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
  });
  // filter functions
  var filterFns = {
    // show if number is greater than 50
    numberGreaterThan50: function() {
      var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
      return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
    },
    // show if name ends with -ium
    ium: function() {
      var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
      return name.match( /ium$/ );
    }
  };

  // bind filter on radio button click
  $('.filters').on( 'click', 'input', function() {
    // get filter value from input value
    var filterValue = this.value;
    // use filterFn if matches value
    filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
}

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

/* clear fix */
.isotope:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
}

.element-item > * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali          { background: #F00; background: hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.alkaline-earth  { background: #F80; background: hsl(  36, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.lanthanoid      { background: #FF0; background: hsl(  72, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.actinoid        { background: #0F0; background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.transition      { background: #0F8; background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.post-transition { background: #0FF; background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.metalloid       { background: #08F; background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.diatomic        { background: #00F; background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.halogen         { background: #F0F; background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.noble-gas       { background: #F08; background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mfzy.co/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>

<h1>Isotope - filtering with radio inputs</h1>

<p class="filters">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="*" checked="checked" /> show all
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value=".metal" /> metal
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value=".transition" /> transition
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value=".alkali, .alkaline-earth" /> alkali &amp; alkaline-earth
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value=":not(.transition)" /> not transition
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="numberGreaterThan50" /> number > 50
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="filter" value="ium" /> name ends with &ndash;ium
  </label>
</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DQydj/) fiddle for the checkbox.

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container'),
      $checkboxes = $('#filters input');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });

  $checkboxes.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
    // ['.red', '.blue'] -> '.red, .blue'
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
  });

  $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    $container.isotope('shuffle');
  });

  var $items = $container.children();


});
```